# function not running correctly on load

Tags: javascript, html, storage, local

I have a page which has various div boxes that change colour when clicked, I then need to get the colour of these boxes on a later page and so I am using local storage for this.

The problem is the user may never actually click the box to change its colour and so it's initial colour should be saved (hence calling the function on load).

At the minute however on load nothing is being saved to the designated storage, I click the box it changes colour, still nothing is saved. On the third click the RGB colour is saved to the local storage however I need it to be saved immediately.

Below is my abbreviated code.
Thanks

```
        <body onload="PremiershipClicked()">

    <div class="Row">
            <div class="League" id="Premiership" onclick="PremiershipClicked()">Premiership</div>
            <div class="League" id="Championship" onclick="ChampionshipClicked()">Championship</div>
    </div>

        </body>
<script>
function PremiershipClicked()
    {
      var color = document.getElementById("Premiership").style.backgroundColor;
      localStorage.setItem("PremiershipColour", color);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: wrap the code in window.onload,it should work as it is

Comment: `document.getElementById("Premiership").style.backgroundColor` will be an empty string. You haven't given it a colour.

Comment: You have your `<script>` outside of your `<body>` tag. You should put the script in your `<head>` tag if you are going to call it on the body.onload